# Pandas DatetimeIndex get next date excluding weekends

Tags: python, pandas

I have two variables `a` and `b`.

`a` is of type `DataFrame`.

`b`'s type is `Series`.

`a.index` contains most of the nonweekend dates in the year of  2020.

`b.index` contains some dates that I picked up randomly.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
print(a.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07',
               '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-13',
               '2020-01-14', '2020-01-15',
               ...
               '2020-12-18', '2020-12-21', '2020-12-22', '2020-12-23',
               '2020-12-24', '2020-12-25', '2020-12-28', '2020-12-29',
               '2020-12-30', '2020-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=245, freq=None)


print(b.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-03', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-10',
               '2020-03-13'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

How can I get the next date of `b.index` within `a.index`?

My first idea is running

```py
target_dates = b.index + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
a.loc[target_dates]
```

But this would result in `KeyError: "[Timestamp('2020-03-14 00:00:00')] not in index"` error.

This is because `2020-03-14` is weekend, so `a.index` doesn't contain this date.

The final result that I want to get is

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-04', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-05', '2020-03-11',
               '2020-03-16'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to create this `DatetimeIndex` by using `a.index` and `b.index`?

Comment: Would you consider providing [mcve]? I'd like to see how `b` is defined.

Comment: What about [`Index.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.shift.html)? As in `b.index.shift(freq="B")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `searchsorted` and make sure `a` was sorted

```
a[np.searchsorted(a.index,b.index)+1]
```

Comment: I was wrong, `b` are of type `Series` instead of `DataFrame`.

Comment: @Brian then just call b.index

Comment: I got `ValueError: object too deep for desired array` error for running `np.searchsorted`.

Comment: @Brian adding index for a as well ~

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my final solution is `a.iloc[np.searchsorted(a.index,b.index)+1]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by the fact that `b` is a series with date as index. So let assume `b` is a dataframe (you can eventually use `b.to_frame`).

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.date_range("2020-01-01", periods=245)})
b = pd.DataFrame({"Date":
                  ['2020-02-03', '2020-03-02', 
                   '2020-03-04', '2020-03-10',
                   '2020-03-13']})
b["Date"] = b["Date"].astype("M8")
```

## Filter

Now you want dates in `a` that are equals to dates in `b` plus 1 day and not weekends. For the latter you should ask that `a["Date"].dt.weekday` is not 5 or 6.

```py
a[a["Date"].isin(b["Date"] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)) &
  ~a["Date"].dt.weekday.isin([5,6])]
```

```sh
         Date
34 2020-02-04
62 2020-03-03
64 2020-03-05
70 2020-03-11
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the data in `a.index` contains "MOST" of the nonweekend days, which means that it contains a few weekend dates.
This is because the dates of `a` represents the stock market opening days in Taiwn. 
So checking `~a["Date"].dt.weekday.isin([5,6])` doesn't work in my case. 
Anyway, I'm still going to give you 1 upvote. Because it might work for other people's cases.

Comment: Hi Brian, can I ask in which timezone are your Date? According to [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html) 5 and 6 are Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: The real problem is that `a` contains a few weekends.

For example, my `a` contains `2018-03-31`, which is Saturday. 

So when `b` contains `2018-03-30`, the function should return `2018-03-31`.

Comment: That's why checking if the date in `a` is not Saturday nor Sunday doesn't work in my case.